# Best way to synchronize eclipse developer environment and integration environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, findbugs, checkstyle

Working on a large project which has spawned a new "side" project. Not quite a child of the first, more like a plugin of substantial size. For various reasons we have decided to develop this new project in a repository separate from our main product's repo. Both products are Maven based and share an Artifactory repository.

With this separation, I have also decided to implement a new integration environment which executes nightly builds of unit and integration tests and uses Sonar to apply Checkstyle and Findbugs analysis.

I'd like ensure that developers and the integration environment of both products remain in sync (i.e. developers are using the same Checkstyle and Findbugs rules as the integration environment is). I'm struggling to define a simple mechanism to do this which does not require new developers to do a lot of manual environment setup.

I'm attempting to create an IDE agnostic code base (i.e. we don't check in .eclipse, .project, etc). I've been looking at several approaches including publishing Checkstyle and Findbugs configuration in a Maven extension artefact. Ideally, these configurations would reside under version control as a dependency but not owning to either of the projects. Changes to the configurations would somehow be propagated to the developer environment and integration environment as transparently as possible.

Previously we used workspace mechanic to setup Eclipse. I'm not entirely against workspace mechanic, but I am wanting to explore alternatives that cater for both the developer environment and headless integration environment equally as well.

Comment: Why can't you use a maven pom and m2eclipse?  The common configuration can go in a parent pom.